# How to add images to gallery programmatically in android or refresh gallery programmatically

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am downloading some of the images from server to sd card in a folder. Images are storing in sd card successfully. But the problem is that at the same time images are not showing in gallery. If i restart the device then it will be showing in gallery.

How can I refresh the gallery programmatically so images can be visible simultaneously whenever I fetch images from server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it, below code will scan your image file and make it available simultaneously to gallery also:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
            new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
        }
    });
```