# How to save Image to external Storage in android?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I want to store Bitmap image in external storage but I am getting an error creating the file directory.

**This is my code.**

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap){
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File directory = new File(root + "/Wallpapers");
        boolean wasSuccessful = directory.mkdirs();
        if(!wasSuccessful){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error Creating directory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt();
        String fname = "Wallpaper-"+n+".png";
        File file = new File(directory, fname);
        if (file.exists()){
            file.delete();
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Wallpaper Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error Saving Wallpaper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**I already write the permission in android manifest.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I've already tried out many solutions but it cannot resolved my issue.

Comment: Permission check ???

Comment: Did you check permission in runtime?

Comment: It is not enough to write permissions in manifest file any more! You must always ask the user to give them and check every time before using.

Comment: @MUmer what error you are getting while saving the image ?

Comment: please have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission)

Comment: Thanks it worked! But the problem is that the saved image is not showing in the gallary.

Comment: You need to scan your image for it to appear in the gallery, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/29714851/2164363

Comment: @MUmer please have to look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792457/captured-image-was-not-showing-in-gallery-but-it-stored-successfully-in-sdcard)

Comment: Thanks to everyone!

Comment: The image is storing in the phone memory not in sd card. What is this error?

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54352821/once-you-have-recovered-an-image-of-the-user-how-to-save-it-in-drawable/54353786#54353786) too

Comment: For save in sd card you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396243/how-to-save-the-image-to-sd-card-on-button-click-android) too

Answer (score 0):

Writing simple example to store bitmapImage Image given as follows. please try it out ...

```
    //Get file name and bitmapImage and call the method ()
    //Bitmap bitmapImage  = ImageUtil.getInstance().changeImageRotated(cameraUri, bitmapImage, ImageUtil.TypeMode.CAMERA);
    //String fileName = String.valueOf(getCurrentTimeStamp());
    //ImageUtil.getInstance().saveImage(bitmapImage, fileName);

    //Here is function to save bitmap image to internal storage
    public Boolean saveImage(Bitmap imageData, String fileName) {
    String savePath = getFilePath(AppConst.getInstance().IMAGE_DIR_APPLY);
    isPathMade(savePath);

    File file = new File(savePath, fileName);

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null;
    boolean keep = true;

    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        imageData.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, AppConst.getInstance().PARKING_APPLY_IMAGE_COMPRESS_QUALITY, fileOutputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        keep = false;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (objectOutputStream != null) {
                objectOutputStream.close();
            }
            if (fileOutputStream != null){
                fileOutputStream.close();
            }
            if (!keep) {
                file.delete();
            }
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e(TAG, "saveImageToCache Exception is " + e.toString());
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```